# CSS how to center a menu

Tags: html, css, menu, center

I can't get a menu to be centered.  I have images, etc. that center just fine, but I can't center the menu.

Here's some of the site's CSS that pertains to the menu:

```
@charset "UTF-8";

    /* CSS Document */

#nav {
    width:975px; /* six main menu buttons at 150px per */
    margin:1 auto; /* Based on a suggestion from stackoverflow */ 
    list-style-type:none;
    text-align:center;
    position: fixed; /* used to render menu bar on top */
    top: 0; /* used to render menu bar on top */
    z-index: 1000; /* use z-index to render menu bar on top of everything, even the slideshow */
    display:inline-block;
    }

#nav li {
    display:inline-block; /* used to wrap text */
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    background-color: #BDB76B; /* menu background color */;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    }

#nav li:hover {  /* highlights current hovered list item when hovering over the parent menu */
    background-color:#BDB76B;
    font-weight:500;
    color:blue;
}

#nav li a {
    display:inline-block; /* used to wrap text */
    margin:5px 0; /*space between menu elements */
    text-decoration:none;
    width:150px; /* this is the width of the menu items */
    line-height:15px; /* this is the text height of the menu items */
    color:#000000; /* list item font color 000=black, FFF=white*/
    }

#nav li a:hover {  /* highlights hovered item of the parent menu */
    background-color:#BDB76B;
    font-weight:500;
    color:blue;
    font-size:18px;
    width:225px;
}

#nav li li a { /* smaller font size for sub menu items */
    font-size:90%;
    background-color: #BDB76B; /* menu background color for submenues */
} 

#nav li li a:hover {  /* highlights current hovered list when hovering over sub menues */
    background-color:#BDB76B;
    font-weight:500;
    color:blue;
    font-size:120%;
    width:200px;
}

/*--- Sublist Styles ---*/
#nav ul {
    position:absolute;
    padding:0;
    left:0;
    display:none; /* hides sublists */
    }

#nav li:hover ul ul {
    display:none;
} /* hides sub-sublists */

#nav li:hover ul {
    display:block;
} /* shows sublist on hover */

#nav li:hover ul ul ul {
    display:none;
} /* hides sub-sub-sublists */

#nav li li:hover ul {
    display:block; /* shows sub-sublist on hover */
    margin-left:150px; /* this should be the same width as the parent list item */
    margin-top:-35px; /* aligns top of sub menu with top of list item */
    }

#nav li li li:hover ul {
    display:block; /* shows sub-sub-sublist on hover */
    margin-left:150px; /* this should be the same width as the parent list item */
    margin-top:-35px; /* aligns top of sub menu with top of list item */
    width:200px;
    }

.upcoming_events_list li { /* attributes for the upcoming_events list level */
    /* CSS to alter the links in the include list when inside the div */
    width: 380px;
    text-align: left;
    list-style-type:circle;
    color:blue;
}

.upcoming_events_list li a:link { /* attributes for the upcoming_events unvisited */
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    color: black;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 300;
    list-style-type: circle;
}

.upcoming_events_list li a:visited { /* attributes for the upcoming_events visited */
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    color: blue;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 100;
    list-style-type: circle;

}

.upcoming_events_list li a:hover { /* attributes for the upcoming_events hover */
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.upcoming_events_list li a:active { /* attributes for the upcoming_events selected */
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Here's a subset of the site's index.shtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><!-- InstanceBegin template="/Templates/ss_template_1.dwt" codeOutsideHTMLIsLocked="false" -->
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="Page_Specific_Title" -->
    <title>My Site Home Page SHTML</title>
    <!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
    <link href="CSS/MySite.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <style type="text/css">
    <!--
    body {
        background-color: #EEE8AA;
         }
    -->
    </style>
    <!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="Page_Specific_Head" -->
<!-- include jQuery library -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- include Cycle plugin -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.slideshow').cycle({
                fx:         'shuffle',  // choose your transition type, ex: fade, scrollUp, shuffle, etc...
                speed:      1500,       // speed at which the transition occurs (in miliseconds)
                delay:      1000,       // time spent on the first slide before starting the slideshow
                continuous: 0,          // true (1) to start next transition immediately after current one completes
                timeout:    9000        // time spent on each slide
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
    <!--
    p {margin:0; padding:0}
    -->
    </style>
    <meta name="description" content="A warm welcome to all. We invite everyone to participate in all aspects of our
    parish life."/>
    <meta name="keywords" content="parish,church,welcome,all are welcome,spiritual,peace,justice"/>
<!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
</head>
<body>
    <!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="Page_Specific_Body" -->
<br />
<div>
<?php include("menu_primary1.shtml");
?>
</div>
<div class="block_center_1000_text_left">
    <!-- The title was created using the Pristina Regular 36 point font.  The background color code is D3AC25-->
    <p align="center">
        <img src="images/front_page_title.jpg" alt="Parish Site"/>
    </p>
</div>
<div class="outer_width_1000" >
</div>
</body>
```

and here's a subset of the included file menu_primary1.shtml:

```
<ul id="nav">
  <li><a href="#">Faith Formation</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="adult_faith_formation.shtml">Adult Faith Formation</a></li>
      <li><a href="Attachments/RelEdGrades1to5Schedule.pdf" target="_blank">Youth Faith Formation Grades 1 to 5</a></li>
      <li><a href="Attachments/RelEdGrades6to8Schedule.pdf" target="_blank">Youth Faith Formation Grades 6 to 8</a></li>
      <li><a href="Attachments/ConfirmationPreparation.pdf" target="_blank">Confirmation Preparation</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Parish Groups</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="Attachments/ChurchGroupsListing.pdf" target="_blank">Listing of Groups and Ministries</a></li>
      <li><a href="good_art_series.shtml">Good Art Series</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact_us.shtml#peace">Peace and Justice Outreach</a></li>
      <li><a href="svdp.shtml">Saint Vincent de Paul</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Upcoming Events</a>
      <?php include("menu_upcoming_events1.shtml");
      ?>
      </li>
... Three other top-level <li> menu items
</ul>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

if you center any element or menu item you have to follow 2 steps:

setp1:

```
ul{
   width: 100%;
   display: table;
   text-align: center;
}
```

step2:

```
ul li{
     display: inline-block;
     float: none;
}
```

and done. That's it now try it yourself.

Comment: Thanks.  That did it.  I changed my first two CSS classes to:

Answer (score 2):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  padding-top: 10px;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.menu {
  background: #093;
}
.menu ul {
  margin-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}
.menu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.menu ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #CC0;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.menu ul li a:hover {
  background: #C30;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Home</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked at you code, but http://howtocenterincss.com may make your life a little happier :)

Comment: Thanks.  I followed their suggestion, putting margin-left:auto; and margin-right:auto; but the menu still did not center.

Comment: I don't know what options you chose on that site, but most of the time it will tell you to use `display: flex`. You may want to investigate that. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: It's a very useful site.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative this can be done with flexbox. Make sure to use your vendor prefixes as required (not included in this example). I prefer this method because a wrapper isn't required.

```css
.menu {
  
}
.menu ul {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  list-style: none;
  width: 500px; /* whatever width you want can be 100% */
}
    
.menu ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Home</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```